# cakephp rest api multiple file uploading

Tags: php, rest, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I trying to upload multiple filesby `REST API` in `cakephp V2.3`. I am running api by `postman` addon of chrome. 
The issue is the format of array of files. Below is the format I am getting. It is hard to get data from the above array. Please guide me how set key to get value in standard format.

```
Array
(
    [Reports] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Chrysanthemum.jpg
                    [1] => Jellyfish.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /tmp/phpDZoRzW
                    [1] => /tmp/phpVyb98b
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 879394
                    [1] => 775702
                )

        )

)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to fetch this data ? your question and question details looking difference.

Comment: no, I am trying to insert data. but when getting data it is in this format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure I got your question right but I think one problem lies in the data format. I assume you are using the `savemany` method. The data is expected in this format:

```
$data = array(
    array('name' => 'Chrysanthemum.jpg', 'type' => 'image/jpeg', 'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpDZoRzW', 'error' => 0, 'size' => 879394),
    array('name' => 'Jellyfish.jpg', 'type' => 'image/jpeg', 'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpVyb98b', 'error' => 0, 'size' => 775702)
);
```

Basically you are providing the data field by field instead of record by record. I don't think that cake can process this correctly.

To get data in the desired format you can either loop through the data or use the convenience method [Hash](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html) that cakephp provides, e.g. by using `extract` on the required keys/values.

**Receive the data in the right format**

If you are able to change the submit-form you name the file input fields like this. The result should be the desired format.

```
<input type="file" name="Report.0">
<input type="file" name="Report.1">
```

This will result in the format:

```
   [Reports] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 'Chrysanthemum.jpg'
                    [type] => 'image/jpeg'
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 'Jellyfish.jpg'
                    [type] => 'image/jpeg'
                )
        )
```

You should use MODELNAME.{n}.FIELDNAME as naming for form fields in Cakephp, though. So if reports is your model it would make sense having a field name for your file-field.

Comment: yes, I want data in the format you explained. I am trying to send files in the  following keys `Report[0]`,`Report[1]` and so on. To get the explained format what I need to change in my key

Comment: Hi Kapil, I extended my answer, covering this aspect as well. You will find more information in the documentation about naming form fields for savemany-tasks: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html